# Why must I use the structure dereference operator rather than just cast a union

Tags: c, unions, dereference

Why do the following two calls to `f` give different output?

```
#include"stdio.h"

typedef union {
  int value_int;
  char value_char;
} my_union_t;

void f(int x)
{
  printf("x: %d\n", x);
}

void main()
{
  my_union_t u;
  u.value_int = 7;
  my_union_t * p_u = &u;
  f( (int) p_u );
  f( p_u->value_int );
}
```

Output:

```
x: -393095784
x: 7
```

Comment: The first is the address of the variable, the second is the value of one member.

Comment: You have not "cast a union" because that is impossible. You have cast a pointer to a union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer points out, you do not want to cast the pointer to an int. You need a dereference.

The compiler will not let you do this:

`f((int) u);`

However, you can get the address, cast to an integer pointer, and then dereference:

`f(*(int *) &u)`

Indeed `u.value_int == *(int *) &u`.

That seems to be the closest you can get to "casting a union to an integer".

Answer (score 2):

`(int) p_u` takes a pointer to a union, which pointer is an address, and casts it to an `int`. Your output looks exactly as I'd expect. `-393095784` is the signed integer representation of some pointer (variable address in RAM memory).

`p_u->value_int` reads the `value_int` from the union, and looks exactly as I'd expect. Know also that `p_u->value_int` is exactly equivalent to `(*p_u).value_int`. `*` is called the "dereference operator." It reads the "contents" of a pointer, or in other words, obtains what is stored in the address the pointer points to. `*p_u` means "read the *contents of* what the `p_u` pointer points to", which contents is the union itself. `some_ptr->` is shorthand for `(*some_ptr).`.

Note that your pointer address overflowed from its unsigned value into the signed value when you cast it to an `int`. Had you not cast it to an int, it would have instead looked like this:

> ```
> Address, assuming your hardware has 64-bit addresses
> AND the address didn't roll over more than once when
> you originally cast it into an `int` type:
> 18446744073316455832
> 0xFFFFFFFFE891D598
>
> Address, assuming your hardware has 32-bit addresses
> AND the address didn't roll over more than once when
> you originally cast it into an `int` type:
> 3901871512
> 0xE891D598
>
> Address, **using the exact pointer size for the hardware
> this code is actually being run on!**:
> 0xffffffffe891d598
>
> sizeof(pointer) on this hardware architecture =
> sizeof(void*) = 8 bytes = 64 bits.
> ```

As you can see above, the 64-bit address printout (1st block) and the "exact pointer size" printout (3rd block) are identical addresses. This means the hardware architecture where I ran the program uses 64-bit pointers. This could also be seen easily by printing the `sizeof(void*)` to obtain the size of any pointer, which I also did. *Note that `void*` is used here just for convenience. Really, you could use ANY pointer type or actual pointer variable there, as the size of a pointer is the same for ALL pointer types on a given hardware architecture.*

The above output was produced by this program which you can run live here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1YSjZt4_:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\nAddress, assuming your hardware has 64-bit addresses\n"
           "AND the address didn't roll over more than once when\n"
           "you originally cast it into an `int` type:\n");
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", (uint64_t)-393095784);
    printf("0x%" PRIX64 "\n", (uint64_t)-393095784);
    
    printf("\nAddress, assuming your hardware has 32-bit addresses\n"
           "AND the address didn't roll over more than once when\n"
           "you originally cast it into an `int` type:\n");
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", (uint32_t)-393095784);
    printf("0x%" PRIX32 "\n", (uint32_t)-393095784);
    
    printf("\nAddress, **using the exact pointer size for the hardware\n"
           "this code is actually being run on!**:\n");
    printf("%p\n", (void *)-393095784);
    
    printf("\nsizeof(pointer) on this hardware architecture =\n"
           "sizeof(void*) = %zu bytes = %zu bits.\n", 
            sizeof(void*), sizeof(void*)*8);
    
    return 0;
}
```

See also the comments under your question.

### References:

1. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf
2. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/
3. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/

Comment: Note that `%lu` will expect a 32-bit value in MS Visual C, not 64. Pointer values should be printed with `%p` so in this case `printf("%p\n", (void*)-393095784);`

Comment: @WeatherVane, great points! To account for different architectures, I updated the code to use the `PRIxN` print specifiers from [`<inttypes.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/), which are hardware-agnostic. I then also added a 3rd print to print the size of a pointer as you show in your comment. Thanks.